# How to get N maximum values of each array from a numpy array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of arrays `x = [[1, 3, 4, 5], [6, 2, 5, 7]]`. I want to get N maximum values from each array of the numpy array: `[[5, 4], [7, 6]]`. I have tried using `np.argpartition(x, -N, axis=0)[-N:]` but it gives `ValueError: kth(=-3) out of bounds (1)`. What is the efficient way for doing this?

Comment: How is `[[1,3],[2,5]]` "N maximum values from each array"?  And I'd be more concerned with doing it *correctly" than "efficiently".

Comment: It's kind of ambiguous what the expected result is, does `np.partition(x, -N, axis=1)[:,-N:]` give the desired result?

Comment: @ScottHunter sorry it was my mistake, I have edited it.

Comment: You got the wrong axis.

Comment: axis=1 just gives the whole array

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by sorting each row and slicing as you want:

```
np.sort(x, axis=1)[:, :2]  # --> [[1 3] [2 5]]    2 minimum in each row
np.sort(x, axis=1)[:, 2:]  # --> [[4 5] [6 7]]    2 maximum in each row
```

Comment: This solution works but `partition` is O(n), `sort` is O(n * log(n)).

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny, I agree. I saw `partition` is corrected by your comment; So, I didn't write that in my answer. Also, the author didn't emphasize on using just `partition` to solve the problem. Again, `partition` is the better choice.